# How to change options in SELECT with CHECKBOX without refresh

Tags: javascript, select

I have select with these options:

```
<select name="kategory" class="select-field">
    <option disabled>ATRACTIONS
    <option value="">
    <option value="Castles">Castles
    <option value="History">History
</select>
```

And I have a check-box:

```
Do you want to eat?<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="restaurants" value="" />
```

after select the check-box, I need to change the select option values to:

```
<option disabled>Restaurants
<option value="China food">Chinas food
<option value="Pizza">Pizza
<option value="Pub">Pub
```

but without page refresh. How can I do that?

Comment: Are you open to using a JavaScript library like jQuery? It would make this a lot easier

Comment: You would be better off making two separate <select> elements, one for attractions and one for restaurants. Then selecting the check box would  hide the attractions select and show the restaurants one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also do this with CSS and a little bit of Javascript.

```
<style>
  #option-switcher select { display: none; }
  #option-switcher.category select[name="category"] { display: block; }
  #option-switcher.food select[name="food"] { display: block; }
</style>

<div id="option-switcher" class="category">
  <select name="category">
    <option value="castles">Castles</option>
    <option value="history">History</option>
  </select>    

  <select name="food">
    <option value="chinese">Chinese</option>
    <option value="pizza">Pizza</option>
    <option value="pub">Pub</option>
  </select>
<div>
Do you want to eat?<input onclick="toggleSelect()" type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="restaurants" value="" />

<script>
  function toggleSelect() {
    document.getElementById('option-switcher').setAttribute('class', 'food')
  }
</script>
```

This works by using CSS to hide the second select element (because the option-switcher div has a CSS class of either "category" or "food"). The onclick() handler of the select box will simply change the CSS class of the option-switcher and the other select box will be shown.

See this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u609sLL9/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Mark up both select boxes but have one hidden by default and then toggle it.

```js
$('input[name="restaurants"]').change(function() {
  $('select[name="category"]').toggle();
  $('select[name="food"]').toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Do you want to eat? <input type="checkbox" name="restaurants" />

<select name="category">
 <option value="castles">Castles</option>
 <option value="history">History</option>
</select>    

<select name="food" style="display: none;">
 <option value="chinese">Chinese</option>
 <option value="pizza">Pizza</option>
 <option value="pub">Pub</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a different approach that separates the data from the choice (not better just different).

```js
//Generalized into a function
function getList(name) {
    $('#Choice').empty().append($('#source optgroup[data-type='+name+']').clone());
}
//Pull default data from Attractions
getList('Attractions');

$('input[name=restaurants]').on('change', function() {
    if($(this).is(':checked')) {
        //Replace with data from Restaurants
        getList('Restaurants');
    } else {
        //Replace with data from Attractions
        getList('Attractions');
    }
})
```

```css
#source {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Do you want to eat?<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="restaurants" value="" />

<select id='Choice'></select>

<select id='source'>
    <optgroup data-type='Attractions'>
        <option disabled>ATTRACTIONS</option>
        <option value="Castles">Castles</option>
        <option value="History">History</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup data-type='Restaurants'>
        <option disabled>Restaurants</option>
        <option value="China food">Chinas food</option>
        <option value="Pizza">Pizza</option>
        <option value="Pub">Pub</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```